# c# sqlite error thrown isSQLite Error 1: 'near "failed": syntax error'

Tags: c#, sqlite

Am looping through an array of strings an inserting them to an sqlite ddatabase but this fails

```
   public static bool SavePermissions(String[] permissions)
    {
        try
        {
          using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename="+ shared.AppDetails.dbname))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
                insertCommand.Connection = db;
                String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + _permissiontbl + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_perm NVARCHAR(2048) UNIQUE)";
                SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

                try
                {
                    createTable.ExecuteReader();
                    deletePermissions();
                     foreach (String i in permissions)
                    {
                        var sql = "insert into " + _permissiontbl + " (user_perm) values ("+ i +")";
                        SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, db);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }


                }
                catch (SqliteException exp)
                {
                    //Handle error
                    Debug.WriteLine("sqlite error thrown is"+exp.Message);
                }
                db.Close();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        }
```

THE ABOVE throws an error

sqlite error thrown isSQLite Error 1: 'near "failed": syntax error'.

Where am i going wrong as am just looping throgh an array of strings and saving them one by one?

Comment: Parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single ticks around the string you're sending to the database.

```
var sql = "insert into " + _permissiontbl + " (user_perm) values ('" + i + "')";
```

Per @DangerZone's suggestion, I do think you should parameterize your query though.

Per @Rahul's suggestion, here is an example of parameterizing your query:

```
var sql = "insert into " + _permissiontbl + " (user_perm) values (@perm)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, db);
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@perm", i));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Good catch .. do also show a parameterized version of this